# When opening a file in perl, how can I automatically use STDIN/OUT if the file name is "-"?

Tags: perl, io

I have a perl program that takes input and output file arguments, and I'd like to support the convention of using `"-"` to specify standard input/output. The problem is that I can't just open the file name, because `open(my $input, '<', '-')` opens a file called `-`, not standard input. So I have to do something like this:

```
my $input_fh;
if ($input_filename eq '-') {
    # Special case: get the stdin handle
    $input_fh = *STDIN{IO};
}
else {
    # Standard case: open the file
    open($input_fh, '<', $input_filename);
}
```

And similarly for the output file. Is there any way to do this without testing for the special case myself? I know I could hack the ARGV filehandle to do this for input, but that won't work for output.

Edit: I've been informed that the 2-argument form of `open` actually does the magic I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it also does some creative interpretation in order to separate the filename from the mode in the second argument. I guess the 3-argument form of `open` is 100% magic-free -- it always opens the *exact* file you tell it to. I'm asking if I can have a single exception for `"-"` while still handling every other file name unambiguously.

Should I just stick my code from above into a subroutine/module and stop whining?

Comment: It turns ouy that there's no built-in way to be magic and not magic at the same time. So I guess I'll just write my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the two-arguments form instead:

```
open ($input_fh, "< " . $input_filename);
```

From `man perlfunc`:

> In the 2-arguments (and 1-argument) form opening "'-'" opens
>   STDIN and opening "'>-'" opens STDOUT.

Note that the `<` mode is optional in the 2-arguments form, so `"< -"`  is perfectly legal.

Comment: Doesn't two-argument open suffer from ambiguity issues, in cases when files begin with `<` or `>`? Or does the concatenation that you showed above (`'<' . $filename`) always eliminate the ambiguity?

Comment: @Ryan I wasn't aware that was a requirement. Just introduce a space between mode and filename, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Well, in theory you could have a file whose name starts with a space. The problem is that the 2-argument open has to interpret the file name no matter what. I like the safety of the 3-arg open in that it will take the file name literally no matter what.

Comment: @Ryan You can't take the file name literally except in the case of "-", can you? :-) Perhaps you can quote white spaces.

Comment: I guess the 2-arg open is the best answer to the question I asked. The solution that I'm going to use is to simply encapsulate the behavior that I want into my own utility subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I'm looking for. There's a nifty module called [`IO::All`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-All/lib/IO/All.pod) that does what I want and more.

For Debian/Ubuntu/similar users, the package is called `libio-all-perl`. I wanted to make that a clickable link to "apt:libio-all-perl", but apparently only http links are allowed here.

---

#### Edit

There's also [`Iterator::Diamond`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejv/Iterator-Diamond-0.03/lib/Iterator/Diamond.pm), which implements the tunable magic that I'm asking for. It's designed for replacing the "diamond" operator `<>`, but it will probably do what I ask if called with just a single file (presumably with some overhead, but who cares?).

Comment: Actually, neither of these modules provides full compatibility with simple filehandles.